# Using the HTML5 <Audio> tag on the desktop version of my website only

Tags: html, audio

Doing research. I would like to use the HTML 5 audio tag on the desktop version of my website only, is it possible to remove it for mobile using @media .

Comment: There is no "Desktop-" or "Mobile-Web", there is just "One Web"! ;-) What criteria should the device meet on which you don´t want the `audio` element?

Comment: I do not want to play audio on any mobile device that supports less than 800px wide. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Did my recommended approach work for you?

Comment: Hi Fabian, I really do think your approach will work, my company has decided against using music on site so When I have a chance I will test in my personal space.

Comment: I appreciated your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to simply not display the `audio` element with a CSS **media query**. In addition to the media query you have to set the **viewport** in a `meta` element.

But be careful in some situations some browsers will load the audio file even though the `audio` element is not displayed.

Here you have the W3C reference for the `audio` element, read about the `preload` attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/audio.html#audio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>audio test</title>

  <style>
    @media (max-width: 799px) {
      audio {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<audio src="some/audio/file.mp3" preload="none" controls>
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</audio>


</body>
</html>
```